# Dedup from union Query in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

In the union I have records from two systems that can be similar and I do not care from which table but I only need to keep one and remove the other.

Here is what the table look like:

[image]

```
Select Agent, ID, System Name, APPID, Sum(Count) From Table 1
Union All Select Agent, ID, System Name, APPID, Sum(Count) From Table 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION instead of UNION ALL will do the job

as an alternative you could also use

```
with base as (
Select Agent, ID, System_Name, APPID, Sum(Count)  as count From Table 1
Union All Select Agent, ID, System_Name, APPID, Sum(Count) as count From Table 2
)
, temp as  (
select Agent, ID, System Name, APPID, count
       row_number() over (partition by Agent, ID, APPID) as rownum
from base
)
select Agent, ID, System Name, APPID, count
from temp
where rownum = 1
```

I have not tested it due to the lack of an iSeries at the moment but at least the idea should get clear I hope

Addition: You could also add an ORDER BY after the PARTITON BY if you need to a have a certain sorting preference

Comment: unfortunately does not because of system field name that i still need to show.

Comment: You also could use row_number function and filter it down to rownum = 1

Comment: Thanks I used your answer and figured it out!